# How to make the root webapp the first one to start in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, liferay

Liferay version: 6.1.1-ce-ga2
Tomcat version: 7.0.42

the webapps always load alphabetically, it will cause some problems since the root webapp is not started firstly. Is there any way we can make root start first?

Comment: Can you specify "some problems" with a bit more detail? Liferay should basically take care of the proper initialization of your application once it's fully deployed. Of course your app shouldn't rely on Liferay being there when the servlet context is started up.

Comment: Liferay start the webapps alphabetically and the problem is:  say we have web1 --> web2 --> root by order, when web1, web2 starts, their PortalLifecycle will be registered in PortalLifecycleUtil._portalLifecyclesInit, but when root starts, it will reset PortalLifecycleUtil._portalLifecyclesInit, so the plugin of web1 and web2 cannot be initialed correctly.

Comment: Can you post error logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no portable way in the java spec, neither standard way in tomcat to do that, however, there's a workaround [described here](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q27)